# iptables v 1.8.4v(legacy): unknown option --string

Tags: python, bash, subprocess, iptables

Here is my python script for calling IPtables and I need SQLite output to make a rule (df2)

```
subprocess.run(["/usr/sbin/iptables", "-A", "INPUT", "-p", "udp", "-m", "udp", "--dport 5060", "-m" "string",
                "--string" , "/home/as/Documents/mydf.csv", "-algo", "bm", "--to 655535", "-j" ,"REJECT"])
```

Error I am getting

```
iptables v 1.8.4v(legacy): unknown option  --string
```

Comment: `"-algo bm"` needs to be two strings:  `"-algo", "bm"`.  Same with `"--to 65535"`.  The path to iptables is wrong, so this can't be your exact code.

Comment: ...and `"--dport 5060"`

Comment: @TimRoberts  I also tried separating all the strings, but no luck, also could you please let me know how to write path location, I am writing path as ```subprocess.call(["/usr/sbin/iptables"(iptable file location),..(all the middle strings separated by " ")....,"/home/Documents/.csv(file location)"])```

Comment: @larsks I tried separating all the string

Comment: What I meant was that, in the example in your question, you have "usr/bin/iptables" without the leading slash.  You do have the iptables-string extension installed?  And why are you using a Windows file path in a Linux system?

Comment: @TimRoberts I am not it is ```/home/as/Documents/.csv```

Comment: This isn't really a bash question, so the bash tag should be removed. This is, however, an iptables question, so the iptables tag should be added.

Comment: This is not a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) yet. The actual problem you are experiencing is with the call to `subprocess.run()`. I suggest simplifying the question by removing the pandas part, and focussing only on the CSV file and the call to `subprocess.run()`.

Comment: GENERAL IPTABLES SUPPORT IS OFF-TOPIC. Support questions may be asked on https://superuser.com. Use this tag only for questions on programming with iptables. Questions about configuring iptables should be asked on Server Fault (https://serverfault.com/tour).

Answer (score 0):

In the code you posted in your answer, you have `usr/sbin/iptables` without a leading slash. You should use `/usr/sbin/iptables`.

You also have several parts in your call to `subprocess.run()` where you needed to separate the arguments into separate list items. You also forgot a comma between `"-m"` and `"string"`.

Try this:

```py
subprocess.run([
    "/usr/sbin/iptables",
    "-A", "INPUT",
    "-p", "udp",
    "-m", "udp",
    "--dport", "5060",
    "-m", "string",
    "--string", "insert csv file location here",
    "-algo", "bm",
    "--to", "655535",
    "-j", "REJECT",
])
```

Comment: Hi, still getting the same error ```iptables v 1.8.4v(legacy): no command specified```

Comment: Then the problem is likely with your `iptables` command, not with your python code.

Comment: Hi, another error ```iptables v 1.8.4v(legacy): unknown option "--string"```